# Is it possible to use the spell checker from 8.5.3 iNotes in a ckeditor richt text control for xpages?

Tags: xpages

We need to have spell checking capability in our application and we need this for IE browsers (which do not have built-in spell checking). I know you can add a plug-in to use the spell checker which uses the Web Spell Checker service. This does not work for us in a corporate setting since it transmits data to a third party service.

Are there any other options any of you have used that might work? Or has anyone found a way to use the spell checker that iNotes uses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked this several times during the XPages Bootcamps and I and several others  have looked for a solution and, to my knowledge, nobody has come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution, but I think your starting point could be to use dojox.editor.plugins.SpellChecker. But I'm not sure it's working and released yet by Dojo. I know it uses some kind of dictionary, so maybe you could use the inbuild notes dict file for this.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/editor/plugins/SpellCheck.html